# How find $\Gamma{\left(\frac{8}{9}\right)}=\frac{9-\sqrt{14}+\sqrt{75-32\sqrt{3}}}{33}\cdot\sqrt[4]{182}$

Tags: calculus, approximation, gamma-function, fake-proofs, transcendental-numbers

show that
$$\Gamma{\left(\dfrac{8}{9}\right)}=\dfrac{9-\sqrt{14}+\sqrt{75-32\sqrt{3}}}{33}\cdot\sqrt[4]{182}$$
where Gamma function：http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function
I found this problem is American Mathematical Monthly (1975,E5952 problem) and post by J.Gilles, and I found this problem can't solution,and I think this is very interesting problem,

How find this problem   solution? Thank you everyone

[image]

Comment: A quick numerical check in Mathematica 8 shows the LHS as about $1.0777588$, while the RHS is about $1.0776991$.  Not sure how accurate Mathematica is with Gammas here, but worth noting.

Comment: oh,meaning that $RHS$ is not true?

Comment: I am not claiming that one way or another yet.  I am just noting the difference in Mathematica, as well as WA.

Comment: if not true, we can find the value?

Comment: maxima also says R.H.S $\ne$ L.H.S.

Comment: Perhaps this is an approximation or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem 5953 (not E) ... Monthly 1974 p 1033 correction...

> [image: Problem 5953]

Solution ... Monthly 1975 p 679

> [image: Solution]

Comment: oh,Thank you,I found sometimes But I can't find this solution,Thank you

Comment: It was a starred problem, meaning neither the proposer nor the editors had a solution.  In 1974, before we all had desktop computers (or even hand-held calculators), it might have looked like a good candidate.  Presumably University of Michigan had a main-frame computer for those calculations.  And that guy in Belgium didn't.

Answer (score 2):

It's surprising the problem made it into the American Mathematical Monthly.

There is a known and conjecturally complete set of situations where a product of powers of $\Gamma(x)$ at several rational values of $x$, is algebraic.  $\Gamma(8/9)$ is not one of them. Allowing powers of $\pi$, there is no way to isolate an individual value of $\Gamma(a/b)$ with $b>2$ using the functional equations, and a simple formula for such a number is very hard to believe.

You can find an abstract description of the algebraic gammas recipe in the considerably more abstract article by Pierre Deligne on L-functions and periods of integrals (or the appendix to that article, written by Nicholas Katz).  This was published later than the Monthly problem, but the part about algebraic $\Gamma$ products was widely understood informally, and not only to experts, for a very long time prior to its formal statement in Deligne's article.